# How can I recover files from Bitlocker encytped HyperV virtual disk?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, data-recovery, hyper-v, bitlocker

I have a virtual disk that I created with HyperV. I encrypted this disk with Bitlocker and put my files in it. I deleted all these files by doing Shift+Delete with a momentary anger and turned off the computer. I turned the computer back on, removed the bitlocker password of the disk and tried to recover the files by trying various recovery programs. The files arrived, but they are corrupt and cannot be opened. I didn't write anything to the disc. How can I recover these files?

Comment: The files are likely encrypted.  I am not sure how you will recover them.

Comment: The files were encrypted. What you want is impossible. Data recovery is impossible

Answer (score 0):

Chances are they are still on the disk, but still in the encrypted form. When you disabled encryption, they were considered non-existent (because they were deleted), and therefore were not decrypted.
Even if you could recover them now, they would be still encrypted - and you cannot decrypt them, because you removed the respective key when decrypting the disk. If you encrypt the disk again, a new key would be generated, and wouldn't help to decrypt those files either.

Looks like you have permanently lost access to their content.